# Inequality between matrix Schatten norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-rank, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Schatten $p$-norm $\|M\|_p$ of a (finite-dimensional) matrix $M$ is defined as $\|M\|_p=\left(\sum_i s_i^p\right)^{1/p}$ where $s_i$ are singular values of $M$.

Let $P,Q$ be positive semidefinite matrices. Show that $$\|P-Q\|_1\le 2\sqrt{\min\left({\rm rank}(P),{\rm rank}(Q)\right)}\ \|P-Q\|_2.$$

How about the case that $P,Q$ are Hermitian matrices?

Comment: Something seems off here. If one chooses $Q=0$ and $P\neq 0$ arbitrarily, then $0=\operatorname{rank}(Q)=\operatorname{min}(\operatorname{rank}(P),\operatorname{rank}(Q))$ so $0< \Vert P\Vert_1\leq 2\sqrt0\Vert P\Vert_2=0$ which is an obvious contradiction. So if there is no mistake in the question, formula etc., this seems to be wrong.